# How to scrape a table on the Invesco website

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this table on the Invesco website by using pd.read_html but I'm not getting the info I'm hoping for. Can someone please help?:

```
import pandas as pd

url = pd.read_html("https://www.invesco.com/us/financial-products/etfs/holdings?audienceType=Investor&ticker=SPHD", header = 0)
```

Comment: You need to send POST request to [this page](https://www.invesco.com/us/financial-products/etfs/holdings/main/holdings/0?audienceType=Investor&action=getEquityHoldings) with payload `{"ticker":"SPHD","grouped":true}` to get table data (in JSON format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. It also contains a way for you to create a dataframe using the scraped info:

```
import pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

SPHD = []

url = "https://www.invesco.com/us/financial-products/etfs/holdings?audienceType=Investor&ticker=SPHD"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("")
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

for table in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(@id,"etf-holdings-table")]//tr'))):
    data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[self::td or self::th]")]
    SPHD.append(data)
    # print(data)

driver.quit()

SPHD_temp = pd.DataFrame(SPHD)
SPHD_temp.columns = SPHD_temp.iloc[0]
SPHD_temp = SPHD_temp.drop([0]).reset_index(drop = True)
```